# How can i set textview text to names that the user input every time i hit a button?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm making a truth or dare app and i need a code that show the user input one by one every time i hit a button

I try somethink i watch in youtube.

So here's the activity that the user input names for the players playing.

```
public class NameInput1Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button SBtn;
Button RTMBtn;
EditText PN1;
EditText PN2;
EditText PN3;
EditText PN4;
EditText PN5;
EditText PN6;
EditText PN7;
EditText PN8;
EditText PN9;
EditText PN10;
String PI1;
String PI2;
String PI3;
String PI4;
String PI5;
String PI6;
String PI7;
String PI8;
String PI9;
String PI10;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_name_input1);

    SBtn = findViewById(R.id.SBtn);
    RTMBtn = findViewById(R.id.RTMBtn);
    PN1 = findViewById(R.id.player1NameInput);
    PN2 = findViewById(R.id.player2NameInput);
    PN3 = findViewById(R.id.player3NameInput);
    PN4 = findViewById(R.id.player4NameInput);
    PN5 = findViewById(R.id.player5NameInput);
    PN6 = findViewById(R.id.player6NameInput);
    PN7 = findViewById(R.id.player7NameInput);
    PN8 = findViewById(R.id.player8NameInput);
    PN9 = findViewById(R.id.player9NameInput);
    PN10 = findViewById(R.id.player10NameInput);




    SBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
   Intent PlayConf = new Intent(NameInput1Activity.this,PlayConf.class);
            PI1 = PN1.getText().toString();
            PI2 = PN2.getText().toString();
            PI3 = PN3.getText().toString();
            PI4 = PN4.getText().toString();
            PI5 = PN5.getText().toString();
            PI6 = PN6.getText().toString();
            PI7 = PN7.getText().toString();
            PI8 = PN8.getText().toString();
            PI9 = PN9.getText().toString();
            PI10 = PN10.getText().toString();
            PlayConf.putExtra("Player1",PI1);
            PlayConf.putExtra("Player2",PI2);
            PlayConf.putExtra("Player3",PI3);
            PlayConf.putExtra("Player4",PI4);
            PlayConf.putExtra("Player5",PI5);
            PlayConf.putExtra("Player6",PI6);
            PlayConf.putExtra("Player7",PI7);
            PlayConf.putExtra("Player8",PI8);
            PlayConf.putExtra("Player9",PI9);
            PlayConf.putExtra("Player10",PI10);
            startActivity(PlayConf);
        }
    });
    RTMBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
Intent RTMBtn = new Intent(NameInput1Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
            PN1.setText("");
            PN1.setHint("Enter a name");
            PN2.setText("");
            PN2.setHint("Enter a name");
            PN3.setText("");
            PN3.setHint("Enter a name");
            PN4.setText("");
            PN4.setHint("Enter a name");
            PN5.setText("");
            PN5.setHint("Enter a hint");
            PN6.setText("");
            PN6.setHint("Enter a hint");
            PN7.setText("");
            PN7.setHint("Enter a hint");
            PN8.setText("");
            PN8.setHint("Enter a hint");
            PN9.setText("");
            PN9.setHint("Enter a hint");
            PN10.setText("");
            PN10.setHint("Enter a hint");
            startActivity(RTMBtn);
            }
        });
    }
 }
```

So i have some 'edittext' that the player input the names and a 'OnClickListener' that passe's the input to 'PlayConf' Activity.
That's the 'PlayConf' Activity:
    public class PlayConf extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Button AddMoreBtn;
Button MoveToToD;
Button RTMBtn;
String PI1;
String PI2;
String PI3;
String PI4;
String PI5;
String PI6;
String PI7;
String PI8;
String PI9;
String PI10;
TextView PTV1;
TextView PTV2;
TextView PTV3;
TextView PTV4;
TextView PTV5;
TextView PTV6;
TextView PTV7;
TextView PTV8;
TextView PTV9;
TextView PTV10;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(com.example.myapplication.R.layout.activity_play_conf);

    AddMoreBtn = findViewById(R.id.AddMoreBtn);
    MoveToToD = findViewById(R.id.MoveToToD);
    RTMBtn =findViewById(R.id.RTMBtn);
    PTV1 = findViewById(R.id.Player1NameConf);
    PTV2 = findViewById(R.id.Player2NameConf);
    PTV3 = findViewById(R.id.Player3NameConf);
    PTV4 = findViewById(R.id.Player4NameConf);
    PTV5 = findViewById(R.id.Player5NameConf);
    PTV6 = findViewById(R.id.Player6NameConf);
    PTV7 = findViewById(R.id.Player7NameConf);
    PTV8 = findViewById(R.id.Player8NameConf);
    PTV9 = findViewById(R.id.Player9NameConf);
    PTV10 = findViewById(R.id.Player10NameConf);


    PI1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Player1");
    PI2 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Player2");
    PI3 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Player3");
    PI4 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Player4");
    PI5 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Player5");
    PI6 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Player6");
    PI7 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Player7");
    PI8 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Player8");
    PI9 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Player9");
    PI10 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Player10");

    PTV1.setText(PI1);
    PTV2.setText(PI2);
    PTV3.setText(PI3);
    PTV4.setText(PI4);
    PTV5.setText(PI5);
    PTV6.setText(PI6);
    PTV7.setText(PI7);
    PTV8.setText(PI8);
    PTV9.setText(PI9);
    PTV10.setText(PI10);

    AddMoreBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent AddMore = new Intent(PlayConf.this, 
NameInput1Activity.class);
            startActivity(AddMore);
        }
    });
    RTMBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent RTMBtn = new Intent(PlayConf.this, MainActivity.class);
            PTV1.setText("");
            PTV2.setText("");
            PTV3.setText("");
            PTV4.setText("");
            PTV5.setText("");
            PTV6.setText("");
            PTV7.setText("");
            PTV8.setText("");
            PTV9.setText("");
            PTV10.setText("");
            startActivity(RTMBtn);
        }
    });
    MoveToToD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
       Intent MoveToToD = new Intent(PlayConf.this, TruthOrDare.class);
            MoveToToD.putExtra("Player1",PI1);
            MoveToToD.putExtra("Player1",PI2);
            MoveToToD.putExtra("Player1",PI3);
            MoveToToD.putExtra("Player1",PI4);
            MoveToToD.putExtra("Player1",PI5);
            MoveToToD.putExtra("Player1",PI6);
            MoveToToD.putExtra("Player1",PI7);
            MoveToToD.putExtra("Player1",PI8);
            MoveToToD.putExtra("Player1",PI9);
            MoveToToD.putExtra("Player1",PI10);
            startActivity(MoveToToD);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

That's the 'PlayConf' Activity, it shows the input so the user see all the input's he enter.So i get the input from the previous Activity 'NameInput1Activity' and make another String from the input 'PI1'.Then i pass the input to the 'TruthOrDare' Activity with the Button 'MoveToToD'.
So that's where i have the problem the 'Truth or Dare' Activity:

```
public class TruthOrDare extends AppCompatActivity {

String PI1;
String PI2;
String PI3;
String PI4;
String PI5;
String PI6;
String PI7;
String PI8;
String PI9;
String PI10;
TextView PlayerView;
Integer TurnCount = 1;
Button RTMBtn;
Button Darebtn;
Button Truthbtn;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_truth_or_dare);

    PI1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Player1");
    PI2 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Player2");
    PI3 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Player3");
    PI4 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Player4");
    PI5 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Player5");
    PI6 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Player6");
    PI7 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Player7");
    PI8 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Player8");
    PI9 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Player9");
    PI10 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Player10");

    PlayerView = findViewById(R.id.PlayerNameTextView);
    RTMBtn = findViewById(R.id.RTMBtn);
    RTMBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent RTMBtn = new Intent(TruthOrDare.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(RTMBtn);
        }
    });
    Truthbtn = findViewById(R.id.TruthBtn);
    Darebtn = findViewById(R.id.Darebtn);
    Truthbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent Truth = new Intent(TruthOrDare.this, TruthActivity.class);
            TurnCount++;
            startActivity(Truth);
        }
    });
    Darebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            TurnCount++;
        }
    });
}

public void ResetCount(View view) {
    TurnCount = 1;
}

public void TurnCountIfElse(View view) {
    if (TurnCount == 1) {
        PlayerView.setText(PI1);
    } else if (TurnCount == 2) {
        PlayerView.setText(PI2);
    } else if (TurnCount == 3) {
        PlayerView.setText(PI3);
    } else if (TurnCount == 4) {
        PlayerView.setText(PI4);
    } else if (TurnCount == 5) {
        PlayerView.setText(PI5);
    } else if (TurnCount == 6) {
        PlayerView.setText(PI6);
    } else if (TurnCount == 7) {
        PlayerView.setText(PI7);
    } else if (TurnCount == 8) {
        PlayerView.setText(PI8);
    } else if (TurnCount == 9) {
        PlayerView.setText(PI9);
    } else if (TurnCount == 10) {
        PlayerView.setText(PI10);
    }
    else {
        TurnCount = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

So what i do here is i make an 'onclicklistener' for the 'Truthbtn'
that add 1 to 'TurnCount' so the when i click the 'TurnCount' Value equals 2
so is set the textview to 'PI2' but instead of that it goes to the last 'else if' and set textview text to 'PI10'
IF YOU NEED ANY OTHER INFO LIKE XML'S JUST SAY IT PLS.

Comment: On click Truthbtn you're calling a Intent named TruthActivity why? Can you please explain ?

Comment: Where exactly did you call the last two methods?       TurnCountIfElse() and ResetCount()

Comment: sorry for not expaining match.So The truth activity is not so match the problem i write the whole code so some points make sense i call TruthActivity because its a part of the app its not so relevant with the problem.

Comment: the TurnCountIfElse is have to be called in the Truthbtn.onclicklistener and Darebtn.onclicklistener  sorry for that.The ResetCount is when the player press the RTMBtn.setonliclicklistener to go to The Menu so the value's of all the integer's like TurnCount Reset IS NOT a part of my problem.

Comment: Then try calling the method and see.

Answer (score 0):

**Dear Friend** You made minor mistake during implementation. You send Same key value During intent on MoveToToD Button Click.
**You use Same key Value Player1 for all player list value**.That's the actual problem.So kindly  Change Your MoveToToD click method and Write Below Code.

```
MoveToToD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
   Intent MoveToToD = new Intent(PlayConf.this, TruthOrDare.class);
        MoveToToD.putExtra("Player1",PI1);
        MoveToToD.putExtra("Player2",PI2);
        MoveToToD.putExtra("Player3",PI3);
        MoveToToD.putExtra("Player4",PI4);
        MoveToToD.putExtra("Player5",PI5);
        MoveToToD.putExtra("Player6",PI6);
        MoveToToD.putExtra("Player7",PI7);
        MoveToToD.putExtra("Player8",PI8);
        MoveToToD.putExtra("Player9",PI9);
        MoveToToD.putExtra("Player10",PI10);
        startActivity(MoveToToD);
        }
    });
```